# Text-to-speech: prosody transfer

Tags: speech-synthesis

Probably "prosody transfer" isn't the right term, but I don't know what would be.

I'm looking for some solution, best would be a software library to use in my own apps, that would allow me to:

- Record an utterance.
- Also provide a text transcription.
- Play it back using a different voice, but with intonation, stress, rhythm, etc. preserved from the original recording.

Alternatively, I'm also interested in ways of annotating the text with prosody information before feeding it into a text-to-speech system.

Could you please suggest me some software or libraries (preferably free and open-source, or at least cheap), or even just pointers about where to read up on such topics? Thanks.

(Note that I'm a software engineer, but new to TTS.)

Comment: You have covered price but what about platform(s)?

Comment: Did you find anything?